# Pan and center google map marker on click

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using Google maps API to display multiple locations which works fine. I have added link which i want to use to center a locations when the corresponding link is clicked.

I have added onclick to center to the location, but its not working

```
<a id="1" href="#">Go to 1</a><br>
<a id="2" href="#">Go to 2</a><br>
<a id="3" href="#">Go to 3</a><br>
<a id="4" href="#">Go to 4</a><br>
<a id="5" href="#">Go to 5</a><br>

var labels = '123456';
var labelIndex = 0;

var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],

  });
};

$("a").click(function(){
//zoom in on location

  var id = ($(this).data('id'));
   google.maps.event.trigger(id , "resize");
   map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
   map.setZoom(14);
  return false;
});
```

[Project on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gz43tqq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have update your code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gz43tqq/3/

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[id][1], locations[id][2]))
    return false;
});
```

you can get id from **a** use function **setCenter(LatLng object)**

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gz43tqq/5/

**working code snippet:**

```js
var labels = '123456';
var labelIndex = 0;

var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var markers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
  });
  markers.push(marker);
};

$("a").click(function() {
  // labels start at 1, array starts at 0
  map.panTo(markers[this.id-1].getPosition());
  map.setZoom(14);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div>
  <a id="1" href="#">Go to 1</a>
  <br>
  <a id="2" href="#">Go to 2</a>
  <br>
  <a id="3" href="#">Go to 3</a>
  <br>
  <a id="4" href="#">Go to 4</a>
  <br>
  <a id="5" href="#">Go to 5</a>
  <br>
</div>
```